# variable path in console python for linux and windows

Tags: python-3.x, console, subprocess

I think there is a simple solution of my problem, but I can't execute my python script in console: I mean I have my script in subdirectory of my project - 'lib' folder and I want to run it with path matched to both linux and windows:

```
path_to_mb_util = join('lib', 'my_script')

os.system(r'python path_to_mb_util %s %s' % (input_folder_path, output_folder))
```

It works fine if I write absolute/relative path (/home/evgenia/Documents/projects/Maps/lib/my_script or lib/my_script) but if I define path as variable I get 'No such file or directory'

I tried using [this recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43506852/8129993) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/773582) but subprocess module doesn't working.

Where I am wrong?

my code for linux:

```
regions_dir = '/media/evgenia/var/regions'
reverse = {v: k for k, v in func.dict_regions(maps_type).items()}
list_folders = os.listdir(regions_dir)
for input_folder in list_folders:
    folder_path = join(regions_dir, input_folder)
    if reverse.get(input_folder[4:]):
        output_folder = join(out, maps_type, reverse.get(input_folder[4:]) + '.mbtiles')
        # path_to_mb_util = join('lib', 'my_script')
        os.system(r'python lib/my_script %s %s' % (folder_path, output_folder))
```

Comment: maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621233/python-configparser-cannot-search-ini-file-correctly-ubuntu-14-python-3-4/30625670#30625670 .

Comment: @hiroprotagonist, the same error: No such file or directory(

Comment: it's difficult for me to help if i do not see the code you have now....

Comment: @hiroprotagonist, I edited my question and added the code

Comment: depending on your current working directory the python interpreter you call with `os.system` will not find `lib/my_script`. you need to make sure that path will always be found; e.g. with `script_path = join(HERE, 'lib/my_script')` (and `HERE` defined as in my other answer) and then call `os.system('python {} {} {}'.format(script_path, folder_path, output_folder))`.

Comment: 1. HERE = Path(\__file__).parent.resolve(); 2. script_path = join(HERE, 'lib', 'my_script'); 3. os.system('python {} {} {}'.format(script_path, folder_path, output_folder)) fails 'TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'PosixPath'' (replacing \__file__   -->   \__my_script.py__ gives error)

Comment: I get it! script_path = join(str(HERE), 'lib', 'my_script.py') works fine, thanks! It is necessary to convert it to string